# fuse is installed but compiler is saying "no package 'fuse' found

Tags: linux, fuse

I'm trying to compile a C program and it tells me

```
user@cu-cs-vm:~/Downloads/pa5$ make
gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra `pkg-config fuse --cflags` fusehello.c

Package fuse was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `fuse.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'fuse' found

fusehello.c:21:18: fatal error: fuse.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

When I try to install fuse, it just tells me it's already installed.

```
sudo apt-get install fuse
```

I looked in `usr/lib/pkgconfig` and `fuse.pc` wasn't there. Should it be there?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know which distro you are using, but you probably need to install `libfuse-dev`. The fuse header files are missing.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/issues/99) the instructions of the comment by ElectricRCAircraftGuy worked.